# What is the naming convention of thrift namespaces if I have a multiword name?

Tags: namespaces, naming-conventions, thrift

In a thrift file, when I have a multiword namespace such as `someAwesomeNamespace`, what is the naming conventions to make this as a namespace in a `.thrift` file?

```
namespace rb someAwesomeNamespace
namespace rb SomeAwesomeNamespace
namespace rb some_awesome_namespace
namespace rb some-awesome-namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: There is none. Use whatever fits your needs (and what the syntax allows).